# Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line ... Fatal Error when replacing value by newcommand result using pgfmathparse

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, texlive, pgfmath

When I build the following code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\halve}[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{int(#1 / 2))}
    \pgfmathresult
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=100pt, paperheight=100pt, margin=0pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt, y=1pt]
            \draw[xshift=\halve{100}, yshift=\halve{100}] node[anchor=north west, text width=40, align=justify] {
                Should have anchor in the middle};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the **Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line ...** Fatal Error

Do you know why and how to solve this?

If I replace `\halve{100}` by 50 everything goes well.

By the way, is there anything lighter in syntax than this \pgfmathparse followed by \pgfmathresult to do computations?

Comment: the reason for the split with `\pgfmathresult` is exactly this, `\pgfmathparse` is not expandable you need to do `\pgfmathparse` first then use `xshift=\pgfmathresult`  or you can use an expandable arithmetic such as `\def\halve#1{\numexpr#1/2\relax}`

Comment: or `\usepackage{xfp}\newcommand{\halve}[1]{\inteval{#1/2}}`.

Comment: Thank you to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

While the commenteres already gave you alternative solutions by

- using expandable TeX math, i.e.

  ```
  \newcommand*\halve[1]{\numexpr#1/2\relax}
  ```

  or
- the LaTeX3 (but since a few months incorporates into LaTeX2) `\inteval`.

there's also a PGFkeys way for this: The [`.evaluated` handler](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#handlers/.evaluated).

With this you can just do

```
xshift/.evaluated = 100/2
% or
yshift/.evaluated = int(100/2)
```

or with

```
\newcommand*\halve[1]{int(#1/2)}
```

you can use

```
xshift/.evaluated = \halve{100}
```

However, since TikZ throws a lot in PGFmath anyway, the last one isn't even needed:

```
xshift = int(100/2)
yshift = \halve{100}
```

works just fine with this definition of `\halve`.

---

However, your usage of TikZ is wrong anyway. All coordinates and transformations are only relative to everything else in the TikZ picture. The shifting does nothing because there's nothing else in your picture.

At the end of the `tikzpicture` environment, TikZ packs everything in a tight box and *returns* that box to TeX. Where this is placed is in TeX's hand now. (Except for the special node `current page` in combination with `remember picture` and `overlay`.)

Anyway, in the code below there are three ways to achieve that anyway, even without TikZ at all.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=100pt, paperheight=100pt, margin=0pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]
  \node [text width=40pt, align=justify] at (current page.center) {
    Should have anchor in the middle};

\pagebreak

\centering
\vspace*{\fill} % that's not TikZ's \fill!
\tikz
  \node [text width=40pt, align=justify] {
    Should have anchor in the middle};
\vspace{\fill}


\pagebreak

\centering
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{40pt}
    Should have anchor in the middle
\end{minipage}
\vspace{\fill}
\end{document}
```